# Vba Excel: Userform closing by itself on End Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 userforms wherein by clicking on `cmd2_click` of `userform3` pops-up `userform4` . On unloading `userform4` ,the code is working as intended. However,`userform3` is unloading by itself on `end sub` of `cmd2_click`

I am unable to find what is causing the unloading of `userform3`. Following is the code.As said previously, `cmd2_click` is executing as intended. All the values are copying to respective cells.The problem only is at end of the code.

```
  Private Sub Cmd2_Click()
  Dim rwcnt, i As Long
  Set ws = Nothing: Set ws = Sheet4
  UserForm4.Show
  If Label14.Caption = 1 Then
  here:   With ws
    rwcnt = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: rwcnt = rwcnt + 1
    .Cells(rwcnt, 1) = TextBox1.Text
    .Cells(rwcnt, 11) = Det22.Text
    .Cells(rwcnt, 12) = Format(Now(), "DD/MMM/YY")
    
    For i = 2 To 10
        If i = 4 Then i = 5
        .Cells(rwcnt, i) = Me.Controls.Item("Det" & i).Text
        Me.Controls.Item("Det" & i).Enabled = True
        Next i: i = 0
    End With
    Set ws = Nothing
    Det22.Enabled = True
    If Label14.Caption = 3 Then GoTo here1
    Clear
    GoTo Ending
    End If


   If Label14.Caption = 2 Then
   here1: Set ws = Sheet8
    With ws
    rwcnt = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: rwcnt = rwcnt + 1
    .Cells(rwcnt, 1) = TextBox1.Text
    .Cells(rwcnt, 5) = Label19.Caption
    .Cells(rwcnt, 11) = Det22.Text
    .Cells(rwcnt, 12) = Format(Now(), "DD/MMM/YY")
    
    For i = 11 To 18
        If i = 14 Then i = 15
        .Cells(rwcnt, i - 9) = Me.Controls.Item("Det" & i).Text
        Me.Controls.Item("Det" & i).Enabled = True
        Next i: i = 0
        Frame4.Enabled = True
        For i = 1 To 3
        If Me.Controls.Item("Optionbutton" & i).Value = True Then
        .Cells(rwcnt, 10) = Me.Controls.Item("Optionbutton" & i).Caption
        .Cells(rwcnt, 9) = TextBox17.Text
        Me.Controls.Item("Optionbutton" & i).Value = False
        End If
        Next i: i = 0
      Frame5.Enabled = True
      Det22.Enabled = True
    End With
    Set ws = Nothing
    Clear
    GoTo Ending
End If

    If Label14.Caption = 3 Then
    GoTo here
    End If

 Ending:
 End Sub                'UF4 is unloading by itself here


 Public Sub Clear()
 If Det7.Text = "Yes" Then
 For i = 13 To 22
    If i = 14 Then i = 15
    If i = 19 Then i = 22
    Sheet6.Cells(Label12.Caption, i) = ""
     Me.Controls.Item("Det" & i).Text = ""
 Next i
 Cmd2.Enabled = False: Cmd4.Enabled = True
 Else
 Sheet6.Cells(Label12.Caption, 22) = "": Det22.Text = ""
 Cmd2.Enabled = False: Cmd4.Enabled = True
 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: All that use of `Goto` can be replaced by regular flow-control: it makes your code hard to review and reason about, and typically is considered bad practice.  Goto is best reserved for error handling and a few situations where it's really the only good solution, like breaking out of deeply-nested loops.  Having said that, I don't see anything which would be causing the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Make sure you have "Break in class module" set for your error handling option in the VB editor options dialog.

Comment: Agreed. The reason for `Goto` was simply because  `userform3` was terminating if I replaced it with `Exit Sub`. It was for experiment,forgot to remove that. To my surprise above problem is not happening when I opened the excel today. Strange!!